# Ubuntu 18.10 - cannot disable on-screen keyboard on touch screen laptop

Tags: 18.10, onscreen-keyboard

This keyboard is super broken and pushes/pulls my windows off the screen every time it appears, which is every time I'm in a text input box.  There has to be a way to disable this system-breaking feature.

Setting on-screen kbd to off in Accessibility Options did nothing.

Comment: same problem here. it is really frustrating. any luck? I tried installing the Block Caribou extension, and also installing Onboard in hopes it would take precedent (Onboard has the option to disable it when a hardware keyboard is attached). Neither thing worked :(

Comment: @G.Meyer No luck.  This is such horrible problem that I'm just avoiding using that OS right now, though sadly 18.04 doesn't run properly on my XPS 15.  If I wasn't busy I would track this down in source and fix, as it is truly a shame.  This has to be a problem for more people than just us, considering how remarkably poorly it works.  I am puzzled how more people are not vocal about this.

Answer (score 3):

After several hours of investigation, it turns out I'm a moron and the Block Caribou extension actually does the job:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/

I went deep into the nuts and bolts of the GNOME Shell source, came up with a solution, realized it was exactly the same as what this extension does, and then realized the extension didn't work when I tried it because I applied it wrong. *facepalms*

Anyway that should get it working. We should probably file a bug report with GNOME though because I agree it's basically unusable with this thing moving windows around all the time.

(even though the new OSK isn't Caribou, that extension just replaces the touchscreen check that automatically activates the keyboard with a function that always returns `false`. So it doesn't care that the OSK isn't Caribou any more).

Answer (score 0):

The Caribou blocker does in fact work.  And you can use it from Firefox as well.

On my part, both TopBar and onscreen keyboard were activating in conjunction with each other whenever my external monitor was attached creating major usability problems so I had to deactivate them both.

The documentation is lacking but after installing the browser and shell component, you may need to logou/reboot and you will see the control toggles on the same Gnome extensions page you downloaded them from.

Hope that helps anybody having issues.

Working like a charm on my machine.